# Print packing slips from excel, possibly using InDesign mail merge?

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, merge, adobe-indesign

So this seems like is would be simple but I'm not great with excel and have not been able to find a way to do this.

We need to print out packing slips based off of an excel spreadsheet. We need a new page to print based on information in column A. If the value is the same in column A all of those rows containing that value should be grouped together and print on one individual sheet. In my example attached there are 4 different values in column A - so the final out put would be 4 separate packing slips printed.

Idk if this can be done through excel alone or if a data merge into indesign would be useful?

I have attached two images as an example what we need to do. One is of  the spreadsheet containing all of the information used and the second is of how we would need the information grouped. Currently we do this by copying and pasting everything by hand which takes a great deal of time considering the spreadsheets we get contain 100s of rows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could use a pivot table on a separate sheet

Answer (score 0):

You know that location 'K071' match Contact 'John Smoltz', however Excel cannot know.

You can either:

- add an explicit match, logic, between the two tables & ask the question again
- add a formulla such as follow (Not very beautifull though):

`=if($A2="K071","john Smoltz",if($A2="K122", "Phil Nikro", "Unknown user"))`